# How to comment on template files? (.tpl)

Tags: php, html, css, templates, comments

I am trying to do some commenting on a .html.tpl file I'm maintaining using

```
<!-- -->
```

but it would return syntax error.

How do you put comment on such files?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Solved! To comment on such files...I should use

```
{* INSERT COMMENT HERE *}
```

Comment: Are you using some particular templating library? This doesn't appear to do anything in pure PHP, for me.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Sorry, just saw your comment after 7 years. I used to maintain a project using "Smarty template engine" back in the day. :)

Answer (score 4):

My file name is `product_form.tpl`
It works to me.

```
<!-- INSERT COMMENT HERE -->
```

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on template engine you are using. Some of them have no comment feature at all. You should carefully read documentation or browse source code if possible.

On my previous job I had to deal with really obsolete code from 90s with few internal-written template engines and at least in one of them I didn't find any comment feature after reading internal documentation. After browsing the code I realised that the template logic flow was based on top of few `preg_replace` calls with no comment feature implementation at all.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
{%* INSERT COMMENT HERE *%}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the approved answer is correct only in that specific case.
For example, in OVOLogistics PDF Generator for CS-CART all the following comments types don't work.

```
<!-- INSERT COMMENT HERE -->
{%* INSERT COMMENT HERE *%}
{* INSERT COMMENT HERE *}
```

As igronus said

> It totally depends on template engine you are using. Some of them have no comment feature at all. You should carefully read documentation or browse source code if possible.